# PHP : How to setup Query to see if database table column contains a specific variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got the following PHP code (simplified).  What I need to do with the query is find out if there is a match in a table of database where column1 = $field1 AND column2 contains $ABC (from array).  Here is the format of the columns in database table.

Table Columns and example entries:

```
id - int(11) Auto-Increment
column1 - varchar(128)   example entry: Hello There
column2 - varchar(128)   example entry: 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, etc.
```

PHP Code

```
$field1 = $_POST['field1'];
$checked = implode(',', $_POST['Array']); 
foreach ($_POST['Array'] as $ABC) {
$query = $conn->query("");
}
```

Information on Array:
The `$_POST['Array']` is a series of checkboxes with values of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10, 11, 12, etc. etc. etc. depending on how many there are.  All numbers.

example : `<input type="checkbox" name="Array[]" value="12"> 12`

How would I write the query to check to see if there is a result of `column1 = $field1 AND column2 CONTAINS $ABC`.

Would something like `WHERE column2 LIKE '%{$ABC}%'` work?  I just found something using that as an example.  I've never setup a query with this before, so not exactly sure how it works.

### NOTE:

I need to make sure that if $ABC = 2 ... it doesn't see 12 in the database and return that the table contains 2.

Comment: Google "many-to-many"

Comment: @zerkms - I read a slight article on "many-to-many" and it goes over relationships between multiple things like authors and books and it said that it will probably require a third junction table and sounds way more complicated than what I need here.  All I need to do is see if there is a result using `WHERE column1 = $field1 AND column2 CONTAINS $ABC`.  I just don't know how to write it and I don't get how many-to-many would be beneficial from what I am gathering.  It is talking about an author can have multiple books and a book can have multiple authors and use many-to-many to query that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FIND_IN_SET` on `column2` to search value of `$ABC`.

***Example***:

```
$ABC = 2;
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( '$ABC', RELPACE( column2, ' ', '' ) )
```

It returns a positive integer if found a match for the value in `'$ABC'`, otherwise a `'0'`.

***Other samples***:

```
-- 0 (not found)  
SELECT FIND_IN_SET( 2, '1, 2, 3' );  
-- 2 (found at 2nd *position*)  
SELECT FIND_IN_SET( 2, REPLACE( '1, 2, 3', ' ', '' ) ); 
-- 1 (found at 1st *position*)  
SELECT FIND_IN_SET( 1, '1,2,3' );
```

***Refer to***:

- [MySQL: FIND_INT_SET(str,strlist)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

  - Return the index position of the first argument within the second
    argument

Comment: Can this be used in conjunction with another where clause?  For instance,  `SELECT count(id) FROM table WHERE column1 = '". $field1 ."' AND FIND_IN_SET( '$ABC', REPLACE(column2, ' ', ''))"`  Also, is that the right format?  I'm assuming by the replace that the string needs to be  '#,#,#,#,#' instead of '#, #, #, #' right?  If I change how this is stored to the '#,#,#,#' can I get rid of the replace and just use FIND_IN_SET('$ABC', column2) ??

Comment: 1. You can also include another condition like `AND`, etc.
2. `FIND_IN_SET` fails if values are separated with both comma and space. Hence `REPLACE` a space char with empty string.
3. You can use `FIND_IN_SET` directly with `column2` so long as values are just comma separated and no space after comma.

Comment: I have demonstrated the same in my *sample* examples.

Comment: Yes you did, I apologize.  I overlooked that.  Would it be a better format (and a valid format) to use  `"SELECT IF(FIND_IN_SET('$ABC',column2)>0,1,0) FROM table WHERE column1 = '". $field1 ."'"` ?  I'm not sure if that would work.  Being if there is a result, I want to do something different than if there isn't a result found.  And there can only be 1 result or none.  Just checking options.  Thank you for your quick replies.

Comment: You can simply use `SELECT FIND_IN_SET('$ABC',columns2)>0 as value_found FROM table WHERE column1 = ?'`. Better go with Prepared Statements.

Comment: Awesome, I really like this method.  Let me go ahead and add this in and I'll accept your answer as well as soon as I get it working.  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Can I do a join ON table2.column = '$ABC'?  Example: `"SELECT FIND_IN_SET('$ABC',table1.column1)>0 as variable1, table2.column1 as variable2 FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table2.column1 = ". $ABC ." WHERE table1.column2 = '". $field1 ."'"`  ?  I've only done this in comparing 1 row in 1 table to another row in another table.  I've never done this based on variables

Comment: We can join. I suggest you post a new query on this requirement.

Comment: huh? what do you mean?  I'm sorry.

Comment: I mean, it would be better explaining a requirement in a question rather than discussing over comments. But, my answer for use on joins is, yes, we can.

Comment: nevermind, I figured out the issue.  Everything works and I am now accepting your answer.  Thanks.